# Virtual Pentesting Lab on popular Enterprise level UTM and SIEM

Tags: penetration-test, siem

I’m planning to add a new Penetration Testing Segment to my personal “Pen Lab”. It’ll be centered around Vulnerability Assessments /Penetration Testing on market leading Next-Gen Enterprise SIEM,UTM,Firewalls Etc.
The following Enterprise Level Information Assurance Software I wish test:

**Network IDS:**
Cisco 2900 3500XL
Juniper M or T
Cisco 5000

**Firewall Antivirus:**
Palo Alto Network VM-Series
Watchguard Gateway Antivirus
NOD32 for Kerio WinRoute Firewall

**Host IDS:**
SNIPS AKA NOCOL
SentryTools

**UTM:**
Fortinet-FortiGate
Sophos
WatchGuard

These are just to name a few of the” Enterprise level Information Assurance solutions” I’m interested in testing. The costs associated with these UTMs are rather high and I was hoping someone could suggest cost effective way of testing them in Virtual Environment(VMware Workstation).

Any help is appreciated!